# How to control invoking of directive

Tags: angularjs

In this plnkr : 
https://plnkr.co/edit/F0XsOPZKq5HArFo9vtFs?p=preview

I'm attempting to prevent a custom directive being invoked by the use of ng-show. But if check console output when the directive is invoked 4 times :  `console.log('invoked')` But ng-show shows/hides html elements it does not control what is rendered within the custom directive itself.

Is there a mechanism to pass the ng-show to the custom directive and if it's false then do call the directive ? I think could pass a new variable to the directive which contains same value as ng-show and then wrap the body of the directive in a conditional ?

src :

```
goob.html : 
goob

http-hello2.html:
2. http-hello2.html

index.html : 
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head> 
  <body>

  <div ng-controller="FetchCtrl">

<label>Filter: <input ng-model="search"></label> 

<div ng-show="false">
<div ng-repeat="sourceUrl in sourceUrls | filter:search track by $index ">
  <status-viewer  url="sourceUrl">   </status-viewer>
</div>
    </div>
</div>

 </body>
</html>

mytemplate.html : 
<!--<h1>{{url}}</h1>-->
<div>
    <p>{{model}}</p> 

</div>

script.js : 
var myapp = angular.module('app', []).controller('FetchCtrl', FetchCtrl)

myapp.directive('statusViewer', function ($http , $interval) {
            return { 
                restrict: 'E',
                templateUrl: 'mytemplate.html', 
                scope: {
                    url: '='
                },  
                link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {

                    console.log('invoked')


                    scope.isFinishedLoading = false;

                    $http.get(scope.url).success(function (data) {
                         scope.model = data;
                    });
                }
            };
        });

function FetchCtrl($scope, $http, $q , $parse) {


$scope.sourceUrls = [
                'http-hello2.html'
            ,'http-hello2.html'
            ,'test.html'
            ,'goob.html'];



} 

test.html : 
test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `ng-show` you should use `ng-if` directive to avoid directive linking before show

[Forked plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/El7gu1DLy4vBFbigncnV?p=preview)